# Regular Expressions that is true if the word "bad" is not in the string

Tags: regex

I am parsing a feed and need to exclude fields that consist of a string with the word "bad", in any combination of case.

For example "bad" or "Bad id" or "user has bAd id" would *not pass* the regular expression test,

*but* "xxx Badlands ddd" or "aaabad" *would pass*.

Comment: probably useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word?rq=1

Comment: What delimits the word "bad" ? You'll probably see a lot of `\bbad\b` but that's not really correct. A regex 'word' is not really a language word.

Comment: This question is somewhat interesting on two grounds (although I'm not sure it warrants being a non-duplicate of the linked question): 1) It asks for a *negative/inverted* result on the test ("would not pass"), 2) It asks only for finding "bad" as a whole/distinct word (such that "bad" and "badlands" yield different results).

Comment: In what programming language are you using regular expressions? What have you tried already? Please elaborate in your question.

Comment: @Brian Regular expressions are generally better (easier to understand) when written in the "would pass/match" case - is it absolutely vital that the negated logic is *inside* the regular expression, or could `!match(re)` (to invert the result) simply be used in the programming language?

Comment: I am voting to close as a duplicate. I changed the example in the answer to the accepted answer of the linked question to `^((?!\bbad\b).)*$` (where `\bbad\b` is trivially "word-boundary,b,a,d,word-boundary") and it works per the rules in the question. Make sure to use the `/i` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude anything that matches `/\bbad\b/i`

The `\b` matches word boundaries and the `i` modifier makes it case insensitive.

Comment: This would match when it *is* true.

Comment: I don't disagree. However, such information (when it is pertinent) should be incorporated into replies. The poster - for whatever reason, of which I have asked for clarification in a comment - stated the requirement is find to find the inverted "would not pass" case. Honor this request by at least acknowledging it the answer.

Comment: @user2864740: I think derp recognized a potential [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. +1 from me.

Comment: @Ruud I have no issue with XY problems being answered for Y. I do have an issue with answers *ignoring* the X. How easy would it be to simply add *one sentence* to the (mutable) answer? Anyway, this answer is still wrong (wrt X) and coffee seems more exciting at the moment..

Answer (score 0):

For javascript, you can just put your word in the regex and do the match `\b` stnads for boundries, which means no character connected :

```
/\bbad\b/i.test("Badkamer") // i for case-insensitive
```

Comment: THe question is updated, didn't knew that was required.

Comment: This still matches in the positive case (so at the very minimum a disclaimer is warranted).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regex:

```
^(.*?(\bbad\b)[^$]*)$
```

[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bM9bU7/3)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to split the string into words, then check each word for a match, It could be done with a function like this:

```
    private bool containsWord(string searchstring, string matchstring)
    {
        bool hasWord = false;

        string[] words = searchstring.split(new Char[] { ' ' });
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (word.ToLower() == matchstring.ToLower())
                hasWord = true;
        }
        return hasWord;
    }
```

The code converts everything to lowercase to ignore any case mismatches. I think you can also use RegEx for this:

```
static bool ExactMatch(string input, string match)

{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input.ToLower(), string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(match.ToLower())));
}
```

\b is a word boundary character, as I understand it.
These examples are in C#. You didn't specify the language